# is percentage sign necessary in formula for converting risk ratio to percentage change?

Tags: excel, percentage

Please dont mark this question as low grade. I am really new in this field and need some help understanding.

I have my risk ratio in an excel file. I want to convert them to risk ratio. I am using following formula

```
=100 x (RR-1)%
```

So when I convert the value of RR to % by the above formula, for example, RR= 0.995 and %change becomes -0.004

But I have seen at some places formula as:

```
=100 x (RR-1)
```

with the above formula, for example, RR= 0.995 and %change becomes -0.45 which seems more understandable.

I have two questions: which formula is correct to use in the above ones?

secondly, does - the percentage sign means 0.45% less risk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here doesn't reside in the formula, but in the understanding of 'the nature of percentage' itself.

If your risk ratio (RR I suppose) equals 0,995, it's also equals to 99,5%. 0,995 and 99,5% are the same number, just represented in 2 differents ways. To swap the 1st to the 2nd representation, use the cell format:

- Standard --> RR = 0,995
- Percentage --> RR = 99,5%

Comment: Dear Vincet, So you want to say that 0.995 of risk ratio refers to 99% decreased percentage risk? How is that explainable? Value of RR near to 1 is less risk, and risk becomes relatively more less as value goes more far from zero. For example a value of 0.899 is 89% less risky? this explanation does not seem understandable. However, if we use the basic formula for RR conversion to percentage change RR-1*100..the answer makes more sense than..In my case 0.99RR becomes 0.5% less risk which is understandable? Isnt it? or can you refer to some book to understand RR to percentage change?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem in the first place. What does your risk ratio represent ?
If your value goes from 1 to 0,995, then it means you decreased by 0,005 which is 0,5% (0,005 * 100). So assuming you're talking about risk, and that your RiskValue went from 1 to 0,995, then it means your risk decreased by 0,5% (it is 0,5% 'less risky').

Comment: Thank you. Yes. Now I can relate to your answer more.